# Get the class of the superclass the extends an abstract class

Tags: java

Let's say I have

```
abstract class Base {
    protected static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(/* What do I do here */);
}
```

And two classes that extend it:

```
class A extends Base {
    // I want to have access to LOGGER with A.class classname
}

class B extends Base {
    // I want to have access to LOGGER with B.class classname
}
```

Is this possible without using template variable?

Comment: You can do that but without having LOGGER as static.

Comment: Add a logger to each class and to the base class. If you want the logger for the implementor in the base class, take one in the ctor and pass the `private static final` logger through. But generally, I like the logger to log from the specific class the logger lives in.

Comment: You can get the subclass from `Base` by calling `getClass()`.

Comment: @shmosel that's an instance method, no?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Good point. Maybe `LOGGER` can be made an instance variable.

Comment: Where do you want to access it from?